# Chrome lost default focus control when use autofill _ login form (20170629_chrome 59.0.3071.115)

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-chrome

could someone help in with this problem with newest update of chrome (version 59.0.3071.115)?

Our login form has 3 textbox instead of normal 2. First is the schema name (e.g country code), second is username (e.g anonymous), last is password (e.g ****). We use codebehind `this.schemaname.Focus();` to focus in this first textbox when user open login form.

But now when user save username, password, chrome use autofill then focus to second textbox - usename, instead of default first textbox (schemaname). And this is my problem.

It begin from 2017/06/29, maybe newest update from chrome version 59.0.3071.115.

So how to config this new chrome for this problem, or anyway to set programmatically by C# codebehind or javascript/JQuery for Asp.Net?

Thank for any help!

Comment: Any luck finding out the way to reproduce or fix this?

Comment: @ShantanuNirale not yet my friend. We even call `$(function () { window.setTimeout...` and it look like ok. Then we type the first character, it appear, and focus in password textbox again :(